# How to cover the line with image?

Tags: html, css

I tried to cover up the lines with images like this :

[image: example]

The following is the code :

```
<html>
<style>
img {
border-radius:100%;
position:relative;
}
hr {
position:relative;
width:555px;
}
</style>
<body>
<center>
<img src="bat.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
<hr>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Result :

[image: screenshoot result]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hey did you know you can embed html/css/javascript within stackoverflow?

Comment: Do you want to build a border around the image?

Comment: @FreedomPride yes :)

Comment: I would look at using two relative layouts within a div.

Comment: `<style>` should be place inside `<head>`, which is missing from your HTML code.  Missing DOCTYPE as well.

Comment: @Raptor Actually, the `<style>` block can appear inside the `<body>` element as long as it is scoped. This requires (a) HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE  html>`) and (b) a `scoped` attribute on the style element. In any case, current browsers are pretty relaxed about them, and that’s not what is causing the issue above. I agree that the `<img />` indicates that the document is int XHTML, which is technically very fussy, but that may not be the intention.

Comment: The `width` anbd `height` attributes of an `img` elements should be pure integers which are already measured in `px`. Adding the `px` will invalidate them, so they will be ignored at best.

Comment: But the style tag appears **outside** body in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}

img {
  border-radius: 100%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:150px;
  width:150px;
}

hr {
  position: absolute;
  width: 555px;
  top:50%;
  z-index:-1;
  border-color: #000;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300" alt="Image"/>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: That's incorrect. `height` and `width` attributes are deprecated, and contain no units. Use CSS instead. Remember to add `alt` attribute. `<center>` tag is also deprecated & removed from web standards.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Thank you ! :)

Comment: I'm Glad that I could help @J.Daisy

Comment: @Raptor I cannot find any evidence that the `width` and `height` attribute are deprecated for `img` elements. Certainly for other elements. According to MDN, what has been deprecated in HTML5 is the use of percentage values in `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 0):

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgpfb0q5/)

HTML

```
<center>
<img src="https://imgs-tuts-dragoart-386112.c.cdn77.org/how-to-draw-batman-easy_1_000000011507_5.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" />
<hr>
</center>
```

CSS

```
center{position: relative;}

img {
border-radius:100%;
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
}
hr {
position: absolute;
width: 555px;
top: 50%;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: That's incorrect. `height` and `width` attributes are deprecated, and contain no units. Use CSS instead. `alt` attribute is missing as well. `<center>` tag is deprecated & removed from web standards.

Answer (score 0):

As per discussion you're looking to build the border around the image but the position i'm not sure of your requirement .

`<img src="something.jpeg" class="img"/>`

For a simple thin border:

```
img { 
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   height:150px;
   width:150px;
}
```

The "Double Border":

```
img {
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   height:150px;
   width:150px;
}
```

Double Border with different inside border color:

```
img {
   padding:1px;
   border:1px solid #021a40;
   background-color:#ff0;
   height:150px;
   width:150px;
}
```

Comment: That's incorrect. `height` and `width` attributes are deprecated, and contain no units. Use CSS instead.

Comment: @Raptor, fixed it. I didn't realize it was deprecated but thanks for the heads up.

Comment: also missing a semicolon at the last line of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `relative` positioning, with comments in the CSS.

The trick is:

- Use `relative` positioning
- Use `z-index` to put one element in front of the other (requires `absolute` or `relative` postitioning.
- With `relative` positioning, `top` and `left` become adjustments.
- Horizontal centering can be achieved using three properties

  - `display: block;`
  - `width: …;`
  - `margin: … auto;` (top-bottom to anything, typically 0; right-left to `auto`).

```css
img {
  border-radius:100%;  /* display as circle */
  position:relative;  /* allow z-index   */

  border: 2px solid #666;  /* display border     */
  z-index: 1000;   /* display in front of hr */
  background-color: white;  /* just in case  */
  display: block;   /* to allow centering */
  width: 150px;   /* same as width in img */
  margin: 0 auto;   /* horizontal centering */
}
hr {
  position:relative;  /* Allow adjustment below: */
  top: -85px;   /* Move up from default */
  width: 555px;

  height: 2px;   /* cross-platform thickness */
  border: none;
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a" width="150" height="150">
<hr>
```